# desactualizar de angular 9 a angular 8

Tags: angular

he actualizado recientemente a angular 9, taanto el cli como el proyecto que tenia en 8 y no se sirve correctamente. Ahora estoy intentando desactualizar la version del cli pero no encuentro ninguna forma en la que funcione

Comment: Muy mala idea. Tiene más sentido ver exactamente "que es lo que no sirve correctamente". Especialmente con el entorno NPM, devolverse es abrir una gran cantidad de vulnerabilidades.

Answer (score 0):

No es buena práctica que vayas a hacia atrás en versiones. Es muy probable que todo esto funcione bien porque los cambios que pueden "quebrar" algo son muy pocos. En esta pagina puedes encontrar que debes hacer para migrar la aplicación de version a version https://update.angular.io/. En tal caso, si quieres ir a versiones anteriores en proyecto y en CLI debes de hacer lo siguiente.

1. Cambiar la version del CLI globalmente `npm install -g @angular/cli^<version>` e.g `npm install @angular/cli^8` (desinstala la version existente primero)
2. Actualiza las dependencias y las dependencias dev en el `package.json`
3. Instala nuevas dependencias locales `npm install`

Es importante que debes de actualizar todo las dependencias de angular, por ejemplo los paquetes @angular/... junto RxJS etc. Si utilizas un control de cambios puedes revertir los cambios del packages.json y nada mas instalar la version deseada del CLI globalmente

Comment: Hay que borrar el directorio `node_modules` también, pues la resolución de dependencias transitivas es un fastidio y puede poner líos teniendo versiones más recientes de cosas ahí.